# Flexible task distribution in workers with Celery

Tags: python, celery, worker

**TL;DR:**
Is there a possibility to easily let *the workers decide* which tasks they can work on, depending on their (local) configuration and the task `args`/`kwargs`?

A quick and dirty solution I thought of would be to [`raise Reject()`](https://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#reject) in all  workers that find themselves unsuitable, but I was hoping there's a more elegant one.

---

**Details:**

The application is an (educational) programming assignment evaluation tool - maybe comparable to continuous integration: A web application accepts submissions of source code for (previously specified) programming languages (or better: programming environments) which then need to be compiled and executed with several test cases. Now especially for use in a high performance computing course with GPUs, compiling and executing can not happen on the host where the web application runs (for other cases just think security reasons).

To make this easily configurable for administrators, I'd like to have a configuration file for a worker, where locally available resources, compiler types and paths etc. are configured, which the worker uses to decide whether to work on a task or not.

Simply using different queues and using a custom [`Router`](https://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#routers) does not seem appealing to me, because the number and configuration of queues could vary at runtime and would look a little messy, I think.

Is there an elegant way to achieve something like that? To be honest, the documentation on [Extensions and Bootsteps](https://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/extending.html) didn't give me much guidance on this.

Thanks in advance for any tips and pointers.